# Geometric Relationships/Sine of angles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

In the solution I have been given, it states that $\sin(\alpha) + \sin (\beta) = \sin (\gamma) $

Why is that true? I cannot spot the relation?
[image: Question at hand]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw a perpendicular from  $B$ to $AD$. Call the distance $x$.
$$\sin\alpha=\frac{x}{12}$$
Do the same for $C$. Call the distance $y$.
$$\sin\gamma=\frac{y}{12}$$.
$$\sin\beta=\frac{y-x}{12}=\frac{y}{12}-\frac{x}{12}=\sin{\gamma}-\sin{\alpha}$$